# QT5.0.2 on Win7 -- Update widgets independently and simultaneously

Tags: qt, qt5

Using 5.0.2 on Win 7

I have 2 “ImageLoop” classes [which extend QWidget] where each take up half the screen, split vertically. Each contains a QLabel for displaying a list of jpg files. So, inside a for loop, I give each widget their list of images, and emit a “listfull” signal which I have connected to a slot – “playList” – in each of the two widgets. Unfortunately, it appears that only the first widget’s signal ever gets emitted as only the first widget is ever updated.

I am new to Qt programming and maybe I am misunderstanding the slot/signal system. I thought the pseudocode below would, for each instance, fill the list, emit the signal, and each instance would go off on their merry way — basically each widget simultaneously and independently showing images. So, question is what am I missing? Or am I going to have to spawn each of these in their own thread?

Thanks!

**Pseudocode**

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
     Create ImageLoop instance
     connect(instance, SIGNAL(listfull()), instance, SLOT(playList()));
     instance->FillList(arrayOfImageFileNames);
}

//inside of ImageLoop class
void FillList(arrayOfImageFileNames) {
     //adds all files to an internal list
    //when finished
     emit listfull();
}

//inside of ImageLoop class
void playList() {
     //code to loop through each image and show it
}
```

Comment: Your theory of slots / signals and the pseudo code look ok, but if you post actual code, then you may get the answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
 Create ImageLoop instance
 connect(instance, SIGNAL(listfull()), instance, SLOT(playList()));
 instance->FillList(arrayOfImageFileNames);
}
```

You are expecting this pseudo-code to asynchronously call playList() on both imageLoop instances. What's happening instead is Qt is connecting listFull to playList directly, making this pseudo-code equivalent to:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
 Create ImageLoop instance
 instance->FillList(arrayOfImageFileNames);
 instance->playList();
}
```

My guess is playList is also synchronous, which means it will finish, and only then will the for loop continue to the second ImageLoop instance.

Qt doesn't allow you to have multiple GUI threads, nor can you update the GUI from multiple threads, so you need to show and image then send a signal asynchronously to show the next image.

Chances are, what you really want is to start a timer when fillList() is done that calls a slot showNextImage() after a certain delay.